# Sorting dates correctly using tablesorter and <div>s

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, sorting, tablesorter

I am using a table using s to get the data. This is done because it grabs information from a database and for design purposes it was done that way.
Now I recently got tablesorter to work perfectly fine but I can't make it work with dates, it sorts the rows by the number of the day. I am using the format `dd-MMM-yyyy` (ie. 02-Oct-2011).
I have modified the original code but it is pretty much the same concept. I tried using the `addParser()` it comes with tablesorter but I had no luck.

Here is the HTML:

```
<table class="tablesorter">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <th>A</th>
        <th>B</th>
        <th>C</th>
        <th>D</th>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td id='101' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>20-Oct-2013</div></td>
        <td id='201' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>21-Dec-2013</div></td>
        <td id='301' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>22-Nov-2013</div>&nbsp;<img src="http://miniontours.yzi.me/loading.gif" height="12" width="12"/></td>
        <td id='401' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>23-Oct-2013</div></td></tr>
    <tr>
        <td id='102' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>20-Sep-2013</div></td>
        <td id='202' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>21-Aug-2013</div></td>
        <td id='302' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>22-Jul-2013</div>&nbsp;<img src="http://miniontours.yzi.me/loading.gif" height="12" width="12"/></td>
        <td id='402' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>23-Jun-2013</div></td>
    </tr>
        <tr>
        <td id='103' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>20-Apr-2013</div></td>
        <td id='203' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>21-Mar-2013</div></td>
        <td id='303' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>22-Feb-2013</div>&nbsp;<img src="http://miniontours.yzi.me/loading.gif" height="12" width="12"/></td>
        <td id='403' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>23-Jan-2013</div></td>
    </tr><tr>
        <td id='104' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>03-Jan-2013</div></td>
        <td id='204' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>11-Oct-2013</div></td>
        <td id='304' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>30-Jun-2013</div>&nbsp;<img src="http://miniontours.yzi.me/loading.gif" height="12" width="12"/></td>
        <td id='404' contenteditable='true'><div class='boxes' contenteditable='true' maxLength='11' style='display:inline' vAlign='center'>12-Sep-2013</div></td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

And here is the JS to call the tablesorter that I'm using:

```
$('table').tablesorter({
    // include zeba widgets
    widgets: ['zebra'],
    // initial sort
    sortList: [[0, 0], [2, 0]]
});
```

**Here is the updated jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q22Yj/9/
Just go and try to sort it and see how none of the dates will be sorted correctly

Comment: @PSL has the correct answer for you, but I also noticed you're making the table cells editable. Please make sure to trigger an `updateCell` event on edited cells so they sort correctly ([here is an example](https://github.com/Mottie/tablesorter/blob/master/js/widgets/widget-editable.js#L61-L63) from the editable widget).

Comment: @Mottie yea, for some reason when I call the data from the DB it does not sort the date correctly, everything else sorts fine, except for the dates

Comment: @Mottie I would just need to add the js file to my code?

Comment: Please share the code you are using to deal with the editable content... if you don't have any, then try using that editable widget. Read the comments in the widget code, it shows you where to add code to deal with updating your server.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the [documentation](http://mottie.github.io/tablesorter/docs/example-option-date-format.html) you can provide a date format in the constructor for table sorter for columns like this.

```
 headers: {

        0: {
            sorter: "shortDate",
            dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        },
        1: {
            sorter: "shortDate",
            dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        },
        2: {
            sorter: "shortDate",
            dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        },
        3: {
            sorter: "shortDate",
            dateFormat: "dd-MMM-yyyy"
        },

    },
```

In this case since you are using the valid separators you can also do:

```
 headers: {
        0: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },
        1: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },
        2: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },
        3: {
            sorter: "shortDate"
        },

    },
```

**[Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/ddVhn/)**

Comment: Hey PSL, thanks for your answer, so I figured out why it is not working correctly even though your code makes sense. One of the columns (the most important one) has an image next to the `<div>` with the date and that messes up the sorting. Check out this **jsFiddle:** http://jsfiddle.net/Q22Yj/8/ any idea how this can be solved??

Comment: @randomizertech It works for me .. You haven't applied the code from my answer. http://jsfiddle.net/MVQKM/

Comment: For some reason it's still not working properly even though in the jsFiddle it is

Comment: @randomizertech can you replicate it in a fiddle. I saw your udpated fiddle. It doesnt have the code in my fiddle. Did you add that?

Comment: I don't know what's wrong with it but I cannot replicate it in a fiddle. I think there's a problem on how I'm calling the data from the database